# Get top 100 numbers and read billions of numbers from old spinning disk efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, disk

The input can be large text file:
How do I read billions of numbers from old spinning disk efficiently to get the top 100 numbers?
I am not looking any solution to diving the rows and run on some 50,000 servers and keep getting top 100 rows and keep merging and finally getting  top 100 rows.
I need help in understanding more on that 20 yrs old spinning hard drive, that reads via rotating head.
Could someone help me read that part more efficiently??

You can say map the sector to memory and or map into virtual memory but how do handle the disk rotating part. Read from disk is still slow. What is most efficient way of reading data from hard disk. You can assume we have a huge text file of that billion numbers to get top 100 rows.

Looking for the fastest way to read from old spin disk.

Comment: In *application programming*, just leave the *how to handle real devices* to the *operating system*. Keep the overhead induced by your process' interaction with the OS low: Do not read without a buffer large enough to be in the region of *diminishing returns*, small enough to not overtax the computer's resources. Use mapping where you *can* tell/hint access will be *sequential read*.

Comment: What do you mean with "top"?

Comment: Just copy the text file to a fast SSD?

Comment: An efficent way is, use I/O efficent Selection algorithm. You can divide your data into blocks that each block has size M. M is your memory size. So if we consider N as your size of your data then you can solve your problem in O(N/M).

Comment: With an old hard disk like this it is probably worth defragmenting the disk before you start to reduce overall seek time.  Then read the disk in the largest chunks you reasonably can.  If the disk has a built-in cache then that could impact your read size.

Answer (score 1):

You don't handle the disk rotation or anything like that. Defragment the disk, it will be sufficient.

A disk hardware controller is already designed to take care of the time required to move the head to next track, and sectors have their (angular) position shifted so that the head is ready to read sector 1 from track N+1 just after reading sector Smax from track N. So a defragmentation is nothing more, nothing less than what to do to get the best from the disk.

Then, read data either through memory mapping (`MapViewOfFile` for Windows, `mmap` for Linux), or use a buffer that is a multiple of disk's **cluster** size (not **sector** size). Since you probably don't know this information, go for the max (64 kB usually, often 4 KB on modern filesystems), and multiply heavily... You should at least read 1 MB data at once (`=1024*1024`, not one million).

And never ever try to read from disk simultaneously from multiple threads/process: you'll simply add a ton load of access times and you'll only increase the time needed to read data. Greatly increase it.

You can however safely distribute data to multiple threads, but have ONLY ONE READING THREAD. I however doubt that you'll get any benefit from more than two threads: computing simple comparisons, even on millions of numbers, is still faster than reading them from a hard disk drive on modern computers... But two threads should be useful.

For getting the 100 biggest numbers, with multiple threads, get a fixed, **ordered**, list of 100 numbers. You can initialize it with the first 100 numbers (you'll have to handle duplicates as needed). You keep trace of the minimum value within the list (the tail), and each time you find a bigger one, you insert it in the list, at its place, and you trash the old tail, replaced by the penultimate element.

List have to be protected with a reader/writer mutex, so that any amount of threads can "read" the tail, and list is really locked only when it's modified by a new top-100 value.
So you won't use a lot of memory for finding the numbers, meaning that you can increase buffer's size instead, to keep your threads busy.